# adb root Permission denied

Tags: android, adb, frida

hi i was reading a guide about frida tool and how to us it and it work fine on a simulator
but now i am Trying to us this tool on my pone i am stuck because i cant get access to the root
my code is:

```
127|tulip:/ $ su root
/system/bin/sh: su: not found
127|tulip:/ $ root
/system/bin/sh: root: not found
127|tulip:/ $
```

this is the command i used is `su root` and it work on the simulator soo why it don't work on the real phone?

```
127|tulip:/ $ cd root
/system/bin/sh: cd: /root: Permission denied
2|tulip:/ $
```

also didn't work. if someone already asked it sorry I didn't see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is simply that physical devices don't allow root access by default.

Some devices can be bootloader unlocked and then rooted (eliminates your warranty).

Some devices can be hacked to get root and on some devices it is next to impossible to gain root permissions.

In general the process for rooting a device varies by device. Check xda-developer forums specific for your device for learning how to root your device.

As part of the rooting process the necessary modifications are made to the system and then `su` binary is available.